# Siri suggesting contacts for Calendar scheduling how to turn this off?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, siri, voice-dictation

Let's say I schedule an event using Siri for tomorrow.  I say "Hey Siri schedule coffee tomorrow with Michael at 9 am." Siri will ask me which of the 9 Michael-s in my phonebook do I want to schedule the event with.

Siri forces me to define which Michael I'm meeting with and it's a pain because I know which Michael I will meet.   Does anyone know how to turn off this contact selecting requirement when scheduling an event?

Comment: Have you tried turning off Siri for Contacts?  Go to `Settings -> Contacts -> Siri & Search` and turn off `Show Siri Suggestions for Contacts`.  You didn't mention what iOS version you're running so I'm assuming it's 13.

Comment: I have the same problem and it drives me crazy. Forcing selecting a contact also force sending over an invitation for the event to that contact, which is often undisireable. Can't wait Apple to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this answer is very late, but I just figured out how to solve this problem. If you want to schedule some thing without it suggesting an individual to schedule it with, you can tell Siri to “schedule event named [insert here]“ for example, if I wanted to schedule coffee with John for tomorrow, and I didn’t want to invite anyone named John, I would simply say “schedule event, named coffee with John.” This has saved me tremendous frustration.